# How to send TWO sets of coordinates to GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, parameters, coordinates

lovely to be here.

Quick question.

If you click on the following link: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=53.838061,-1.604025

It will take you to Google Maps and you can see a single pin on the map. This is done by sending two parameters via the URL which, in this case are: 53.838061,-1.604025. These are the Latitude and Longitude coordinates of one location.

What I wish to have is basically two sets of coordinates so I can see two pins on the map.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to use this api: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers

There are also some examples there. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Am taking that you need to know the co-ordinates from the maps page and not via the api.

Right click on the spot, in the menu select "whats here", maps inserts a marker on the spot, coordinates are on the search text box and also on mouse hover on the marker.